# Should a Mercedes snort after it is turned off?

Tags: suspension, mercedes-benz

I have a 2013 Mercedes S550 which has an "air ride" suspension. Some work has been done it to replace bags and pumps and things.

When I turn the car off and get out, I notice that it "snorts" and seems to be exhaling air out of both the front left and right air ride systems.

Is that normal? I don't seem to remember it doing that when I first had the car. I only noticed it after the work was done several months ago.

Comment: My Land Rover discovery has air suspension. When we exit the vehicle, you can hear a quiet release of air as it levels itself, but not a 'snort'. I wonder if some kind of silencer has been left off the air exhaust port.

Comment: I'm betting this isn't something Daimler would want S550 purchasers hearing either, so definitely not normal. Lacking a silencer on the exhaust port seems like a likely thing to me as well as @HandyHowie has stated. Aftermarket bags?